# can I use sprite image in 960 grid system?

Tags: css, sprite, 960.gs

can I use sprite image in 960 grid system? if yes then how to manage the width of a particular sprite image with the grid width. anybody can help me for the above problem?

Comment: Could you pleas be more specific. Maybe provide some examples of the code you are planning on placing the sprite in? Technically you could place a sprite or any element anywhere you want. Also when you say sprite I am assuming you are referring to this. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp : Please provide some more information. Thank you.

Comment: yes Kris Hollenbeck, you are right. actually i have started to use 960 grid system, and don't understand how to use it. so I am asking can i use sprite image file in grid system? can anybody help me how to use 960 grid system? because i am puzzled, how to manage between the width of 960.css with my image width. any easy tutorial or any easy process?

Answer (score 0):

The Process of using the 960 grid is quite easy and the markup is quite quick to learn.

try the following.

```
<section id="wrap" class="container_12">

    <header class="grid_12">
        <h1>This is your Header</h1>
    </header>

    <article class="grid_8">
        <h2>This is a content section</h2>
    </article>

    <aside class="grid_4"?>
        <h3> this is a sidebar </h3>
    </aside>

    <footer class="grid_12">
        <p>this is the footer</p>
    </footer>

</section> <!--end wrap container - this container allows you to use the grid classes and creates your main column -->
```

Check the CSS in the 960 and it will make sense, the grids are divisions of your container so grid_6 would be half the width of the container_12 etc. - grid_8 would be two thirds, aand grid_4 would be a third, obviously, grid_12 would take the full width of the container.

As for using sprites, simply look in the CSS for the width of the grid_ class that you use for the containing element, if you\'re not using one of those classes then the 960 wouldn't interfere with you using sprites at all.